# Flutter, How to fetch a DocumentSnapshot field value from nested maps in the firestore?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to match current user's `IsVegan` property to a product's `IsVegan` property, and if it matches it would display a green check icon otherwise a red x icon.

Currently I have this set up, where I call an instance of `ProductModel` to fetch the product's property which I've successfully done.

`product_card_vertical.dart`

```
Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: product.productPreferences!.isVegan &&
                            // user's [IsVegan] property
                        ? NCircularIcon(
                            icon: Icons.check_circle,
                            color: NColors.primary,
                            height: 33,
                            width: 30,
                            size: 23,
                          )
                        : NCircularIcon(
                            icon: Icons.cancel,
                            color: NColors.red,
                            height: 33,
                            width: 30,
                            size: 23,
                          ),
                  ),
```

And for the user's property I was thinking that a firestore query would be the right approach and this is what I have now:

```
Future<UserModel> fetchUserIsVegan() async {
    try {
      final documentSnapshot = await _db
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(AuthenticationRepository.instance.authUser?.uid)
          .get();
      userMap2 = documentSnapshot.data();
      print(userMap2);
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        return UserModel.fromSnapshot(documentSnapshot);
      } else {
        return UserModel.empty();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw 'Something went wrong. Please try again';
    }
  }
```

But I am now having trouble with fetching a singular boolean value from a nested map in firestore using the `document.get` method but I don't exactly know how to.

This is my db structure:

[firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYBrc.png)

Comment: i understand you're a beginner and you're probably expected to comment on your code as part of your assignment, but seeing `// helper function to get full name` over one line of code is really just clutter to my eyes :)

Comment: ;-; honestly feel the same about the comment but what can i do and thanks for the idea i'll check it out!

Comment: regarding comments, the idea is to explain what code is doing when the function name alone isn't enough. so, a function `getFullName` or `getFormattedName` etc is sufficient to not need any. unfortunately, not a lot of places teach this (something i had to learn myself) so my initial remark was just meant to explain that those aren't useful, but i understand you doing it for the sake of your assignment. if you were to be working on a "real" project, i don't think you'd find these sorts of comments that you're (perhaps forced into) writing now, and not something you can expect going forward :)

Comment: i read your question again, i think i misunderstood it initially, i thought you were trying to update a singular field but seems that's not what you're looking for

Comment: fortunately I am not forced to write those comments! i dont know why i feel the need to comment every function thats already self explanatory maybe its a way of overcompensating for my lack of programming skills. i'm definitely clear on the function of comments now so I would like to thank you for that. and yes im not trying to update a field in firebase ;-;

Comment: You *SHOULD* keep putting those comments in; never be afraid to add them! A year from now when you go back and look at your code, things may not be so clear; comments will help with that. It also helps us to understand the code flow and thought processes. Just ensure they are on point and clearly explain what the purpose is. That being said, what's being asked is a bit unclear and there's  too much code. Big picture is you must access the user model at some point to determine their dietary needs; vegen? true/false. But that really only needs to happen once for the duration of the app run.

Comment: What exactly are you asking and why do you write "as that would require a lot of changes to my code"?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. Thank you @Jay I guess I'll continue writing the comments because it might help me in the future. And I've updated the question, hopefully its a bit more understandable now, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to do it this way

```
final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
Map<String, dynamic>? userMap;

Future<bool> fetchUserIsVegan() async {
    try {
      final documentSnapshot = await _db
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(AuthenticationRepository.instance.authUser?.uid)
          .get();
      userMap = documentSnapshot.data();

      return userMap!["Preferences"]["Diet"]["IsVegan"];
    } catch (e) {
      throw 'Something went wrong. Please try again';
    }
  }
```